# Making a side menu bar ontop of image

Tags: jquery, image, menu

So I am trying to accomplish a few things here. I want to make this side menu over the image. Which I am struggling to do. Second. I am trying to make it interactive so that when you click on a category it stays on the page and new text boxes come up with the information. If you know how to do this and could share, it would be greatly appreciated!

What I am trying to achieve:

Comment: That seems great! Have you read the SO FAQ?

Comment: @roasted `return false;`

Comment: LINK TO WHAT I WANT IT TO LOOK LIKE: http://postimg.org/image/kupzoy535/